# I'm not able to access a certain intranet site

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, connection-issues

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab (3.2 Android OS) on a wireless network to access an intranet site. I can access the site perfectly from a laptop connected (wireless) to the intranet site, but not with the Galaxy Tab. It's saying that it cannot locate the remote server (this is baffling). Additionally, I have tried several browsers: Firefox, Opera, and Android browser. Has anyone experienced something similar or have an idea what the problem may be. Thanks!

Comment: Can it access other intranet sites?  Is the laptop configured to use internal DNS servers?

Comment: No, the laptop is set for dhcp, here at my work. It accesses our intranet with no problem. The Galaxy Tab is using the same wireless profile, and can access all of the usual internet sites, just not our intranet site.

Comment: @Matthew Read - I don't think the laptop has a Connection-specific DNS Suffix configured.

Comment: @MatthewRead - on second look, yes it does. How would I add a Connection-specific DNS suffix to the Galaxy Tab, if this is in fact the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your intranet sites are actually hosted on another subnet, and access is through a proxy server. Direct DNS lookup, and even IP routing to the host may not be possible.

The browser on your laptop might be automatically configuring the proxy, whereas the tab would not. I can be tricky to determine where the proxy server is, however it maybe possible with netstat and a little knowledge.

On the laptop, start downloading a large file from the intranet, and run this from a command prompt:

netstat -an

Look for a connection on a port like 80, 8080, 443, or 8443. This would be the server you need to configure as your proxy server on the tab.

It's also worth exploring the DNS suffix options suggested above.